# Play Framework + Zurb Foundation + webjars

Tags: playframework, zurb-foundation, webjars

I'm starting to learn Play framework and I would like to use it with Zurb Foundation framework and sass compiler.

On Internet, I found Play example with Bootstrap framework but not with Zurb Foundation. Does someone know where to find a basic Play template which use Zurb Foundation ?

Until know, I have done the following step :

- Add the Sass plugin by adding this line into plugin.sbt file :

  ```
  addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.2")
  ```
- Import webjar-play, foundation and js-node by adding these lines into build.sbt file :

  ```
  libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" % "requirejs-node" % "2.1.20"
  libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" % "foundation" % "6.3.1"
  libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0"
  ```

But now, I don't know how to compile scss file and include css and js files into my view.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Caveat: The following is working for me, but I have my own open question around sass and Play!, so there may be "more correct" ways to handle this]

The online-auction-scala example uses Foundation.
https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-scala

Following this example I have this in the build.sbt:

```
lazy val `web-gateway` = (project in file("web-gateway"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala && LagomPlay, SbtReactiveAppPlugin)
  .dependsOn(`monopoly-api`, `monopoly-stream-api`)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      lagomScaladslServer,
      macwire,
      scalaTest,
      "org.webjars" % "foundation" % "6.4.3-1",
      "org.webjars" % "foundation-icon-fonts" % "d596a3cfb3"
    ),
    httpIngressPaths := Seq("/")
  )
```

As you state, adding this to plugin.sbt is required:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.12")
```

Ensure sassify is installed:

```
npm install sassify
```

Add your xyzzy.scss file under app/assets, and it will be compiled to target/web/public/main/xyzzy.css.